# Build a Message

Tags: vb.net

I want to make a Message, using formatting, multiple lines and adding 3 arguments. But I'm having some trouble

```
Public Class vbList

'Declare
Dim users As IList(Of User) = New List(Of User)()

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    users.Add(New User With {
            .Id = 1,
            .Name = "Suresh Dasari",
            .Location = "Hyderabad"
        })

    MsgBox("Id: {0}", users.Item(0).Id.ToString() & vbCrLf & "Name: {0}", users.Item(0).Name) & vbCrLf & "Location: {0}", users.Item(0).Location)
End Sub
```

I don't get this message below. Don't I need to convert the Id to a string to put it in a message?

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "1
> Name: {0}" to type 'Integer' is not valid.'

And whats up with this one, I can't have more than 2 arguments?

> Too many arguments to 'Public Function MsgBox(Prompt As Object, [Buttons As MsgBoxStyle = ApplicationModal], [Title As Object = Nothing]) As MsgBoxResult'.   VSBasics    C:\Users\ljhha\Documents\it\vb\VSBasics\VSBasics\vbList.vb  33  Active

Comment: As the last message clearly states, the second parameter of the MsgBox function refers to the button style, whereas you are specifying a message string. VBA MsgBox is NOT .NET MessageBox.Show. You should merge the first and second parameter with a "&" instead of separating them with a ",".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `String.Format` or string interpolation to insert the variables. You can insert line breaks that way too or use a multiline literal in the first place.

```vb
Dim str1 = String.Format("Date: {0}{1}Time: {2}", Date.Now.ToShortDateString(), Environment.NewLine, Date.Now.ToShortTimeString())
Dim str2 = $"Date: {Date.Now.ToShortDateString()}{Environment.NewLine}Time: {Date.Now.ToShortTimeString()}"
Dim str3 = $"Date: {Date.Now.ToShortDateString()}
Time: {Date.Now.ToShortTimeString()}"

MessageBox.Show(str1)
MessageBox.Show(str2)
MessageBox.Show(str3)
```

Comment: Thanks a lots, I'm really having trouble finding good documentation on Visual Basic. Normally websites like tutorialspoint.com or w3schools.com would help me out with simple stuff like this. If you know some good besides learn.microsoft.com please let me know

Comment: As for documentation: have you had a look at VS itself, more precisely the help? Hit F1 in Visual Studio _(the "real" one, not VS Code)_, select the "Contents" tab and browse through the Visual Basic section there.

Comment: @FlyingNimbus learn.microsoft.com should have good documentation for VB, I'm not sure why you're excluding it as a source.

Comment: For example, If I Google "Visual Basic BindingList" the first link is from learn.microsoft.com but gives me an explanation on BindingList for C#, which is really hard to translate to VB as a beginner. Then I go deeper to  "Implements IBindingList"  doc, to check out all the methods and try them out. half of them don't exist Visual Basic, probably because there are different versions. So that's why I believe the  learn.microsoft.com is do difficult to use.

Comment: @FlyingNimbus, there's no such thing as "an explanation on BindingList for C#". The explanation of the class is independent of language. As for the code examples, you get to choose the language they are displayed in at the top of the page. There are some topics that only have C# examples but `BindingList(Of T)` is not one of them and neither is `IBindingList`. As for the members of those types, they all "exist" in VB because what members a type has is not language-dependent either.